# finding surrounding lines with grep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, grep

I know how to use grep to output a line that matches a string. But what if I also want to output one line above every line containing a matching string, how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do the following

```
grep -B 1 text_to_search_for file.txt
```

Comment: That should be a -B right?

Comment: Sorry, yes. -B for Before. -C is for before and after. Corrected answer, I had misread the question